# ColdFusion cfloop issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfloop

I'm running ColdFusion 2016. I have a `cfloop` which pulls in data from a query, all other ColdFusion queries work fine on the page and if I pull in the same variable in an output outside the loop, it works fine, except the loop is giving me an error. The error output says:

> Variable GPS_LATITUDE is undefined.

Which is correct, as in the database there is no `GPS_LATITUDE` but there is a `GPS_LATITUDE1`.

I need to add the loop number on the end of the variable so as it loops pulls in the data `gps_latitude1`, `gps_latitude2`, `gps_latitude3` not just `gps_latitude`.

My loop code is...

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="3">
    <td><p>#gps_latitude[i]#</p></td>
    <td><p>#gps_longitude[i]#</p></td>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: For only 3 items, I suggest getting rid of the loop and hard coding the column names.

Comment: What does your query look like? And how many rows does it retrieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@elixieru, You can't directly give gps_latitude[i]. which is  not check your query which is consider it as **Array**. I can imagine your scenario and give my sample code about how to get an same columnName with

```
<cfquery name='test' datasource="mytest">
    select * from test
</cfquery>
```

This is my sample query. It's having column name as address1, address2 etc... I'm going to get the data about address1 & address2 like your scenario.

```
<cfloop query="test">
    <cfloop from="1" to="2" index="i">
        <cfset a = test["address#i#"]>
        <cfoutput> #a# </cfoutput> <br/>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Here I'm looping over the query and so some simple / index loop based on my count ( Address1,2,3,4,5 etc ). For now I'm just use 2 like from 1 to 2.

Here I've store the **test['address#i#']** in variable a and print that variable. Now **test['address#i#']** it will consider as **test.address1**

I hope my sample help you more.

Comment: You might want to take another look at the opening sentence.